# How to display shopping cart information in Wordpress / WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and wordpress for an e-commerce website. I want to be able to display the number of items and total price in a user's cart anywhere on the page.

Normally  -- and if you use one of the woo themes -- this shows up in the menu navigation bar.  However, I am using an almost completely blank theme, and I do not know how I can get the item / price total information and display it in html.  Their documentation gives this snippet: 
 http://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/

```
<?php global $woocommerce; ?>
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>`<br>
```

But I do not understand what HTML tag or class I would use to make that display.  What sort of element and class id would I need to use to make this appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the codes below for your theme's functions.php file.

And also this will ajaxify your cart to be updated automatically without reloading the page.

```
// Ensure cart contents update when products are added to the cart via AJAX (place the following in functions.php)
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php

    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

}
```